# Webpack plugin to attach static JSON object to output

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, webpack, javascript-build

I am trying to write a webpack plugin that will go into a directory containing html files, open each, remove new lines, and generate an object to attach as a static property to my output file (which is a var).

The object would look something like:

```
{
  htmlFile1: '<p>some html one!</p>',
  htmlFile2: '<span>some html two!</span>
}
```

Then I would like it to be attached to my output like:

```
App.templates = { .... }
```

The creation of the object is done. I'm just struggling with webpack and figuring out how to attach it to the main object. Should I just write it to disk and require it? Or is there a way to add it to the bundle via the plugin?

I'm using Rivets.js as a template engine and I have not been able to find anything out there that does something like this already.

Also worth noting, all I'm using is webpack and npm. No Grunt/Gulp/etc

Thanks so much!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You could use webpack's [`require.context`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html) to import all html files in a directory as text, process the text, and export the results as a single object:

```
const requireTemplate = require.context('./templates', false, /\.html$/);

module.exports = requireTemplate.keys().reduce((templateMap, templatePath) => {
  const templateName = templatePath.match(/\/(\w*?)\.html/)[1]; // get filename without path and extention
  templateMap[templateName] = require(templatePath);
  return templateMap;
}, {});
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm oblivious when it comes to Webpack. Would this but something in a plugin or in my codebase? And how would I attach the resulting object to the global namespace?

Comment: This would be a module in your codebase not a plugin. You could call it `templateMap.js` and place it next to your entry point. Then you could either use it with `require('./templateMap')` or if you want it added as a global, you could use the [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin) like this: `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({TEMPLATES: "./templateMap"})` and access it as `TEMPLATES` in your app.